# localhost does not render website, only index of, using mamp

Tags: php, localhost, mamp

Using mamp, I have my document root set to htdocs folder. Inside that folder I have the folder with the contents for the site. When I connect to localhost, the page that renders is "Index of /" and then a bullet point with the name of the folder within htdocs.

How can I get the full page to render? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to add the folder within htdocs to the url `localhost/folder` or you need to set your doc root to `htdocs/folder`.

Comment: Read *related* answers first.

Answer (score 1):

A request to `localhost` looks for files in the htdocs folder. If it doesn't find an `index` file (html,php,etc) it displays all the folders in the directory. If your website lives at `htdocs/mywebsite` then you need can view the website at `localhost/mywebsite`.

Otherwise you can move the entire contents of `mywebsite` into the htdocs folder itself.

Answer (score 1):

it sounds to me that you have put your files in a folder in the htdocs
so to access you need to point your browser to the folder

instead of `localhost/mywebsite`

you would need to type `localhost/mywebsite/thenameofyourfolder`

Answer (score 0):

In MAMP preferences, have you set the root folder to the folder you are attempting to serve?

Ensure your httpd and hosts files are configured correctly too!

```
nano /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Comment: when I set the document root to the website folder within htdocs and connect to localhost, a blank page is rendered.